# Spring JPA query for checking boolean property

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, repository

Suppose i have the following entity:

```
@Entity
public class MyClass {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private Boolean isActive;
}
```

I want to check if an object "MyClass" isActive this is what i have done:

```
public interface MyClassRepository extends Repository<MyClass, Long> {
    @Query("SELECT IS_ACTIVE FROM T_MYTABLE WHERE ID = ?1")
    public Boolean isActive(Long id);
}
```

However i get the following error

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Specified result type [java.lang.Boolean] did not match Query selection type [com.myapp.MyClass] - multiple selections: use Tuple or array
```

What is the correct why to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing jpa query with native query.
In your case you should:

Native query:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT IS_ACTIVE FROM T_MYTABLE WHERE ID = ?1", nativeQuery = true)
```

JPQL:

```
@Query("SELECT isActive FROM MyClass WHERE id= ?1")
```